# How can you select elements that contain exactly descendants that match a given selector?

Tags: jquery, css

For example, to select all cells of a `table` which contain only elements matching a selector `selector`, I tried:

```
$('table tr td:has(' + selector + ')')
```

but this also matches cells also containing other stuff.

Then I tried:

```
$('table tr td:has(' + selector + '):not(:has(:not(' + selector + ')))')
```

But this always returns an empty object.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Thanks guys, actually I was doing something wrong it seems, because trying with a minimal fiddle, it does seem to work using the second approach: http://jsfiddle.net/u0r6oehc/1/

Comment: checkout jq `.is()` selector: like `$('table tr td').is('.some_class')`

Comment: can you share the html and selector value

Comment: `$(selector,'table tr')` like this? http://jsfiddle.net/zcf80dqo/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood correctly but you want all td's who has a child with a certain class for ex?

Maybe using [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b9skzoeL/)

Edit: saw your edit now ;)